# !strcmp(locale, "C"):Error:Assert failed:in file baseapi.cpp, line 209

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, tess4j

The example codes for running Tess4j has been given in "http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html," however it was performed in Mac OS in intellij, error message came up with `!strcmp(locale, "C"):Error:Assert failed:in file baseapi.cpp, line 209` with the below messages:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x000000012183ca4f, pid=44026, tid=0x0000000000001903
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64  compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C [libtesseract.dylib+0x156a4f] ERRCODE::error(char const*, TessErrorLogCode, char const*, ...) const+0x183
```

By my reading of the above posts, it appears to be an issue with exporting LC_ALL=C, but not sure, in the example codes given, what exact codes should be added/amend, to make that example to run?

Comment: This might help you : https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/issues/105

Comment: Thanks for that, read the link however no exact solution yet

Comment: https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/165 can give some clue

Answer (score 0):

After entering `export LC_ALL=C` in the terminal, open the IDE in the same terminal window. Running the IDE/code in different terminal won't work.